# dialog box is not getting opened ajax jquery MVC2 asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, modal-dialog

delete dialog box is not getting opened
my code
view:

```
 `<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Delete dialog" style="display: none;">
    <p>
        Are you sure you want to delete the point?
    </p>
    </div>`
```

javascript:

```
 `options += '<div onclick="editPoint(' + id + ')">Edit</div>
    <div onclick="deletePoint('   + id + ')">Delete</div>';
     optionsBox.html(options);`
```

controller:
     public string delete_marker ( string Id )
     {
       try
        {
                mapmaker_dbDataContext DB = new mapmaker_dbDataContext ();
                DB.SP_DeletePoint ( Id, /*"Innayat"*/ User.Identity.Name );
                return "Point successfully deleted";
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
          {
                return "Delete operation failed";
          }
        }

delete function:

```
function deletePoint(id) {

    MapScript.removeOptionsBox();
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).css('display','block');
    alert('in detele');
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({

          resizable: false,
          height:140,
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
            "Delete": function() {                
                var link = '<%= Url.Action("delete_marker", "Home", new { id = "-1" }) %>';
                 link = link.replace("-1",id);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: link,
                        type: "GET",
                        cache: false,
                        success:
                                function (data) {
                                    //alert(data);
                                    if($('.up-triangle.firstAnimationA').length || $('.up-triangle.firstAnimationB').length )
                                        //LoadList(0);
                                        LoadNeighborhoodList(0, MapScript.neighborhoodCenter.latitude, MapScript.neighborhoodCenter.longitude);
                                    if($('.up-triangle.secondAnimationA').length || $('.up-triangle.secondAnimationB').length )
                                        //LoadList(1);
                                        LoadNeighborhoodList(1, MapScript.neighborhoodCenter.latitude, MapScript.neighborhoodCenter.longitude);
                                    if($('.up-triangle.thirdAnimationA').length || $('.up-triangle.thirdAnimationB').length )
                                        {
                                            //LoadList(2);
                                            LoadNeighborhoodList(2, MapScript.neighborhoodCenter.latitude, MapScript.neighborhoodCenter.longitude);
                                        }
                                },
                        error: function(){
                            alert('Delete operation failed');
                        }
                    });
              $( this ).dialog( "close" );
              $( "#dialog-confirm" ).css('display','none');
                alert('delete button clicked');

            },
            "Cancel": function() {
              $( this ).dialog( "close" );
              $( "#dialog-confirm" ).css('display','none');
            }
          }
        });
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog();


}
```

its giving error what wrong with the code? even if i replace the ajax functionlity with an alert its again giving error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your dialog div on load body or document like this ...

```
$(function() {

     $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false});


});
```